# How to download images from "wikimedia search result" using wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I need to mirror every images which appear on this page:

> http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:Search&ns0=1&ns6=1&ns12=1&ns14=1&ns100=1&ns106=1&redirs=0&search=buitenzorg&limit=900&offset=0

The mirror result should give us the full size images, not the thumbnails.
What is the best way to do this with wget?

**UPDATE:**
I update the solution below.

Comment: Instead of adding an "Update" section, answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite difficult to write all the script in stackoverflow editor, you can find the script at the address below. The script only downloads all images at the first page, you can modify it to automate download process in another page.

> http://pastebin.com/xuPaqxKW

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend my friend!
Using cat, egrep and wget youll get this task done pretty fast
Download the search results URI wget, then run

```
cat DownloadedSearchResults.html | egrep (?<=class="searchResultImage".+href=").+?\.jpg/
```

That should give you http://commons.wikimedia.org/ based links to each of the image's web page. Now, for each one of those results, download it and run:

```
cat DownloadedSearchResult.jpg | egrep (?<=class="fullImageLink".*href=").+?\.jpg
```

That should give you a direct link to the highest resolution available for that image.

Im hoping your bash knowledge will do the rest. Good Luck.

Comment: Bro, "word unexpected (expecting ")")" appear when egrep pattern consumed. Could you correcting this ? thanks

Comment: I dont exactly know how egrep handles regex, maybe you have to specify any kind of parameter? try man egrep to see

Answer (score 0):

Came here with the same problem .. found this >> http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikix

I don't have access to a linux machine now, so I didn't try it yet.